# How to detect "Allow notification dot" in app notification on Android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I tried to find many ways to detect "Allow notification dot" [true|false], but it is seem no one answer about this.

[image]

Please help me because I need to detect Badge notification on Android Oreo.
Thanks,

Comment: I don't think there is a method in `NotificationManager` class that satisfies your requirements. btw, why do you need to detect this setting?

Comment: I checked in NotificationManager class, it seem don't have any method to detect "Allow notification dot". I need to detect this because I am implementing App icon to show dot on Android Oreo. It's project requirement.

Comment: you can implement that functionality without worrying about user setting. All you have to do is create a notification channel and set `channel.setShowBadge(true)` on it. it will show the badge if the user doesn't have it disabled. More about the channel and badges [here](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-badges-32e1152eb1a0)

Comment: I already did channel.setShowBadge(true), but if the user disabled parent (Allow notification off), how do we do ? 

In my case if the user disabled parent (Allow notification dot), I will alert dialog to user to enable "Allow notification dot".

Comment: I am afraid you can't read those settings. Let's wait if anyone here knows a workaround.

Comment: Okay, wait anyone answer here. Any way thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you solve problem:

```
if (channel.canShowBadge()) {
   // do something when dot is enabled
   } else {
   // do something when dot is disabled
   }
```

or you can use it like this:

```
 if (channel.canShowBadge()) {
    // do something when dot is enabled
    } else if (!channel.canShowBadge()) {
    // do something when dot is disabled
    }
```

This code is working for me, I tested it on Android 8 and 8.1.

Comment: This doesn't work. Returns `canShowBadge` as true for both enabled and disabled.